# Unable to update Ubuntu on Windows as a WSL

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I'm not able to update Ubuntu for Windows but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. This is what I get when I try to update:

```
jonathan@LAPTOP-QGUCRGG3:/mnt/c/code/new-dashboard-2$ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've looked online for different solutions but so far nothing has worked. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1889]. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to 'update Ubuntu for Windows'. What exactly does that mean?

Comment: I meant as a I'm using Ubuntu as a WSL and I can't update it.